# bash error, missing bracket after command

Tags: bash, sh

I'm getting a bash error when performing a conditional if statment that checks is the current Flask db migration is upgraded or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

# create folders
mkdir log

# migrate the database
source .env

if ! [ python manage.py db current | grep -q '(head)' ]; then
        python manage.py db upgrade
fi
```

The error is:

```
./install.sh: line 9: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

I've read similar posts about this error and the mmost common error is the espace between brackets and the command but I have those spaces.

Comment: You don't put commands inside `[]`.

Comment: That's only if you want to test a conditional expression.

Comment: Just get rid of the brackets.

Comment: yeah conditional like 1=1, thanks